# SSIS Integraion Runtime ADF- Install Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0

Tags: ssis, visual-foxpro, azure-data-factory

I have used the SSIS script task(C# code) to load the DBF File to SQL Server
I have noticed the C# code has reference to the "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0", I have installed and loaded data in my local machine.

Now, I don't have access to install the SSIS Integration Runtime on ADF, I would like to know if the SSIS IR allows us to install the driver "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0"which are not present built in.

Answer (score 1):

Put something similar to this in your main.cmd file that SSIS-IR looks at to install custom things.

```
echo Installing ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server...
msiexec /i msodbcsql.msi /quiet /passive /qn /lv %CUSTOM_SETUP_SCRIPT_LOG_DIR%\msodbcsql.log IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES ADDLOCAL=ALL
echo Installation completed

echo Installing OLE DB Driver for SQL Server...
msiexec /i msoledbsql.msi /quiet /passive /qn /lv %CUSTOM_SETUP_SCRIPT_LOG_DIR%\msoledbsql.log IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES
echo Installation completed
```

Answer (score 0):

SSIS Integration Runtime in ADF can be [customized] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup